# How do I install unetbootin on an E1 Vision AMD processor?

Tags: ubuntu, amd

I'm on Ubuntu on an E1 Vision AMD (64 bit) processor.

The available binaries for Unetbootin do not work on this architecture.

Is there any way that I can get Unetbootin working on this system?

Comment: Compiling it from [source](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/unetbootin/wiki/compile) maybe?

Comment: @illuminÉ That worked, when I last tried it (different link), there were a bunch of errors. Care to post it as an answer?

Comment: Oh, that was just a link and you went through the process so maybe you have some further insights. Please proceed!

Comment: @illuminÉ Nah, following the basic instructions in the link worked. I had followed a _different_ link in the past, which hadn't worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some cases, especially with smaller tools/utilities, one might resort to compiling from source.

In this case compiling as described on the [wiki](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/unetbootin/wiki/compile) worked. Requirements for compiling [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) v585:

- libqt4-dev
- g++

**Instructions (make sure to check the source link)**

1- Extract the tarball and cd to it

2- Run the following commands:

```
lupdate-qt4 unetbootin.pro
lrelease-qt4 unetbootin.pro
qmake-qt4
make
```

3- A dynamically linked executable which you can package will then be generated at "unetbootin"

4- If building a package, place the unetbootin_*.qm files (which were generated from the .ts files when lrelease-qt4 was run) in the /usr/share/unetbootin/ directory to enable the usage of localization.

5- If building a package, add "syslinux", "p7zip-full", "libqt4-core" (libQtCore.so.4), "libqt4-gui" (libQtGui.so.4), and "libqt4-network" (libQtNetwork.so.4) as dependencies.